# Why is this while loop not working?

Tags: php, mysql

This while loop is not performing any of the echo's. I've tested  mysql_num_fields($result); and it gives me 16 so it's not that $i is already greater than $j. It's not going infinite on me either, just doing nothing.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{ 
    $i = 1;
    $j = mysql_num_fields($result);

    if ($i <= $j) {
        echo "<li>";
        echo "<a id='autoload' href='images/big/".$row['card$i'].".jpg' class='highslide'      onclick='return hs.expand(this, config1 )'>";
        echo "<img src='images/small/".$row['card$i']."jpg' alt''";
        echo " title='";
        echo $year." ". $brand." ".$playerfirst." ".$playerlast." ".$details."'/>";
        echo "</a>";
        echo "</li>";
        $i++;
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}
```

I guess I should have said that this query only returns 1 row. I then need to pull a number from several different columns (card1, card2, card3...card16) and put it in as the image file name as you see above. Also I understand all of the mysqli and protection from injection stuff I just don't really need to worry about it with this sort of project.

Comment: @Dagon `$j` and the `if` statement are actually not needed at all.

Comment: true, i did not read the code to closely.

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: Get rid of the `if()` statement - It's not doing what you think and you don't need it. In addition, get rid of `$i` in `$row['card$i']`.

Comment: If I get rid of the '$i' how do I choose a different column each time the loop runs?

Comment: $row changes on every loop, taking the next row from the array, so you don't need to keep track your self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FROM PHP MANUAL**

> Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows. The type of returned array depends on how result_type is defined. By using MYSQL_BOTH (default), you'll get an array with both associative and number indices. Using MYSQL_ASSOC, you only get associative indices (as mysql_fetch_assoc() works), using MYSQL_NUM, you only get number indices (as mysql_fetch_row() works).
>
> If two or more columns of the result have the same field names, the last column will take precedence. To access the other column(s) of the same name, you must use the numeric index of the column or make an alias for the column. For aliased columns, you cannot access the contents with the original column name.

your while will run only for each result.  You should only need to do

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{ 

    echo "<li>";
    echo "<a id='autoload' href='images/big/".$row['card'].".jpg' class='highslide'      onclick='return hs.expand(this, config1 )'>";
    echo "<img src='images/small/".$row['card']."jpg' alt''";
    echo " title='";
    echo $year." ". $brand." ".$playerfirst." ".$playerlast." ".$details."'/>";
    echo "</a>";
    echo "</li>";
    

}
```

Doing this will cycle only through each result.  While there is a row from the result, do this.  Return to the top then do again if there is still a row availabe

Comment: Don't forget to remove the `$i`s :)

Comment: Thanks Elliot B  Missed those

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_num_fields` returns the number of columns in a table returned by an sql query. It doesn't change every row. You shouldn't be running it every loop.

Furthermore, removing the `$i`,`$j` lines and changing the if statement to `if(false)` would do the exact same thing this is doing now, and to fix this problem you remove the if statement altogether...

You need a [php & mysql](http://www.tizag.com/) tutorial.

Comment: I want the number of columns returned from my query, not rows. So that is actually correct.

Comment: 1: The number of columns will always be the same unless you are switching out queries, and even then you will know beforehand how many you'll get back. 2: It is not correct. Read what I said. It should not be run every loop. It should be run once, before the loop, and if you absolutely must have an if statement on a result you know will be 1 or more rows anyway *by definition* it should have been outside the loop too.

Comment: Further, you said in your edit that you are returning only one row with 16 columns. Then why are you looping at all? `mysql_fetch_array` loops rows, there is nothing that loops columns because you don't need to. You need to learn some basic programming constructs like `while`, `if` and arrays.

Comment: I guess it should be outside. i was just using it to set a constant to break the while loop at. 

That doesn't change the fact that this question isn't solved. It isn't echoing anything.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for a shortcut that doesn't exist. I want to create that set of html code for each number in one of 16 different columns. I'm trying to avoid typing the same code 16 times with different numbers.

Comment: Quite frankly, you lack the capacity for me to do anything other than copy paste. If this was written by you, you did it through random trial and error. If it wasn't, this is a homework question. All you need to do is loop through an array. That is day 2 php tutorial stuff. The link in my answer is the answer you need.

Comment: I need to learn to pose my questions better I suppose. None of this solved my problem. It did help me clean up the code a bit, but overall I just learned that people get angry easily.

Comment: You clearly don't understand the very basic programing ideas anyone learns in a 2 hour tutorial: variables, arrays, loops, if statements. How to read documentation. This all comes not from your question, but from the code you wrote up to the third semicolon. Take my original advice and find a tutorial...

Comment: I'm fine with that sort of stuff. this isn't the first thing I've done no matter what you think my code looks like. Like I said I was looking for a shortcut that didn't exist. I need to change my data structure to simplify this.

Answer (score 0):

This is what your code do today:

```
/* as long as i can fetch a database row */
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{ 
   /* reset the counter i */
   $i=1;

   /* count the number of fields */
   $j=mysql_num_fields($result);

   /* as long as its at leas one field ($i is always 1) */
   if ($i <= $j)
   {

      /* print some html */
      echo "<li>";
      echo "<a id='autoload' href='images/big/".$row['card$i'].".jpg' class='highslide'      onclick='return hs.expand(this, config1 )'>";
      echo "<img src='images/small/".$row['card$i']."jpg' alt''";
      echo " title='";
      echo $year." ". $brand." ".$playerfirst." ".$playerlast." ".$details."'/>";
      echo "</a>";
      echo "</li>";

      /* increase counter to 2 (always gets to 2 as i always is 1 before) */
      $i++;
  }

  /* if there was zero field */
  else
  {
      /* break the loop */
      break;
  }

  /* loop by jumping ut to reset counter i */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone has said, this code should be reworked all together.  But to try and figure out the question, you have one row with 16 columns.  You want to print out the list item html 16 times.  What you want is a for loop. The if loop will only run once.

```
for($i=1; $i <= $j; $i++) {
     /* print some html */
      echo "<li>";
      echo "<a id='autoload' href='images/big/".$row['card$i'].".jpg' class='highslide'      onclick='return hs.expand(this, config1 )'>";
      echo "<img src='images/small/".$row['card$i']."jpg' alt''";
      echo " title='";
      echo $year." ". $brand." ".$playerfirst." ".$playerlast." ".$details."'/>";
      echo "</a>";
      echo "</li>";
}
```